# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error when running command Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan

Tags: powershell, azure

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error when running command Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan...

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $rpname = "myrecoveryplan"
    $recoplan = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan -Name $rpname

    Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan : Operation failed.
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    At line:2 char:13
    + $recoplan = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan -Name $rpname
    +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmReco...AsrRecoveryPlan], Exception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery.GetAzureRmRecoveryS 
       ervicesAsrRecoveryPlan
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated My powershell and it seems moving on. But I got another blocker. $Context= Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $Vault
$recoplan = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan -Name $rpname
Start-AzureRmSiteRecoveryTestFailoverJob -RecoveryPlan $recoplan -Direction "PrimaryToRecovery" -VMNetwork "asrtestfailtarget"
Start-AzureRmSiteRecoveryTestFailoverJob : Cannot bind parameter 'RecoveryPlan'. Cannot convert the 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery.ASRRecoveryPlan" value of type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecovery.ASRRecoveryPlan" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.SiteRecovery.ASRRecoveryPlan".
At line:5 char:56
+ ... rt-AzureRmSiteRecoveryTestFailoverJob -RecoveryPlan $recoplan -Direct ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-AzureRmSiteRecoveryTestFailoverJob], Parameter 
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.SiteRecovery.Start 
   AzureRmSiteRecoveryTestFailoverJob